# Replace a part of line that has a given pattern using sed command

Tags: sed

I have a JSON file that has the following contents:

```
{
    "a" : "100"
}
```

Here the number of spaces before `"a"` can vary. So, I want to first check the occurrence of `"a"` in the line and replace the rest of line after `"a"` with `" : "10""` to make the file look like this:

```
{
    "a" : "10"
}
```

How can I do this using sed command? This is what I have tried so far:

```
sed -ir 's/.*a.* [0-9][0-9]*/10/g' file.json
```

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Comment: Also, "How do I do this using X tool" is a highly suspicious question. Sounds very much like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Sed is not the [right tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to manipulate JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use special tools for json. For example [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq)

```
$ jq '.a = "10"' file
{
    "a": "10"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -ri 's/("a"[ ]*:[ ]*).*/\1"10"/' file
$ cat file
{
    "a" : "10"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But I do not know whether the value will be 100 after "a".

Comment: @bhaskarjupudi See my modified answer to meet any values after "a"